# Using FlatLaf in OSGI services

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, look-and-feel, flatlaf

I am trying to use FlatLaf theme in my OSGI services. Currently calling `FlatDarkLaf.setup()` in the first service that initializing. It is working perfectly fine in the same service but outside of that, some swing components could not find UI Classes as example below.

```
java.lang.Error: no ComponentUI class for: javax.swing.JOptionPane[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,icon=,initialValue=,message=com.ekinokssoftware.kabintester.common.AddTakePanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.GridBagLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],messageType=QUESTION_MESSAGE,optionType=YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,wantsInput=false]
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUIError(UIDefaults.java:763)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.getUIError(MultiUIDefaults.java:144)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUI(UIDefaults.java:793)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:1072)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.updateUI(JOptionPane.java:1880)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.<init>(JOptionPane.java:1845)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:869)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(JOptionPane.java:806)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(JOptionPane.java:768)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(JOptionPane.java:729)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(JOptionPane.java:700)
```

I am suspecting this is some kind of ClassLoader problem but don't know how to approach since there are no information about FlatLaf with OSGI. Calling `FlatDarkLaf.setup()` in each service also didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the service that calls `FlatDarkLaf.setup()` to the required bundles in all services that use UI components resolved the issue.